# Cannot Open Files in WinRT Unit Testing

Tags: serialization, windows-runtime, storagefile

I am writing a unit test to validate the serialization of objects and I am able to successfully save the file without any issue. I can even browse the file and validate the contents are correct. However, when I attempt to open the file for reading I always receive an UnauthorizedAccess exception.

Here is the code used to save the item:

```
        public static async Task SaveItem<T>(string folderName, T item)
        where T : BaseBusinessItem
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folderName");
        }

        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        try
        {
            var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
                                             .CreateFolderAsync(folderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            var file =
                await
                folder.CreateFileAsync(item.UniqueID.GetHashCode().ToString(), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            using (var outStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                serializer.WriteObject(outStream.AsStreamForWrite(), item);
                await outStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Here is the code used to restore the item:

```
    public static async Task<T> RestoreItem<T>(string folderName, string hashCode)
        where T : BaseBusinessItem, new()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folderName");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hashCode))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("hashCode");
        }

        var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync(folderName);
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(hashCode);
        var inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        var retVal = (T)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
        return retVal;
    }
```

And the unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestFileSaveLoad()
    {
        await _ds.SaveItem("TestFolder");
        Guid ID = _item.UniqueID;
        _ds = await ItemDataSource.LoadItem("TestFolder", ID.GetHashCode().ToString());
    }
```

Any ideas or troubleshooting steps I might be missing. The unit test app manifest includes the following capabilities: Document Library, Internet (Client). The following declarations are in place: File Open Picker, File Save Picker and File Type Associations.

Thanks!

Comment: It always fails on the line starting with var inStream = file.OpenSequentialReadAsync();

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet helped me accomplish my goal. Hope this is helpful for someone else:

http://codepaste.net/gtu5mq